# Format error when using a custom ControlValueAccessor for an input type=date in Angular2 rc4

Tags: angular, typescript

Before I begin I am using Angular2 **rc4** with typescript. In case you are wondering, I cannot yet upgrade, so I have to make this work within the constraints of **rc4**. In addition I'm an ng2 noob, so still getting my head around concepts and all the changes between the "release candidates".

Having done quite a bit of research about value accessors, I decided to create one specifically for `<input type=date />` to avoid requiring a separate mule property in the component just to turn the date into a string for the input.

I found [this gist](https://gist.github.com/mexx/0a7d94ea087f1736081c), which seemed to do pretty much what I wanted to do.

Using that as a starting, and almost ending, point, I came up with this:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Renderer, forwardRef } from "@angular/core";
import { ControlValueAccessor, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR } from "@angular/forms";
import { isBlank, isDate } from "@angular/forms/src/facade/lang";
import moment from "moment";

export const DATE_VALUE_ACCESSOR: any = {
    provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
    useExisting: forwardRef(() => DateValueAccessor),
    multi: true
};

@Directive({
    selector:
    "input[type=date][formControlName],input[type=date][formControl],input[type=date][ngModel]",
    host: {
        "(change)": "onChange($event.target.value)",
        "(input)": "onChange($event.target.value)",
        "(blur)": "onTouched()"
    },
    providers: [DATE_VALUE_ACCESSOR]
})
export class DateValueAccessor implements ControlValueAccessor {
    onChange = (_: any) => {
        // we don't need to do anything here
    };

    onTouched = () => {
        // we don't need to do anything here
    };

    constructor(
        private _renderer: Renderer,
        private _elementRef: ElementRef) {
    }

    writeValue(value: any): void {
        var normalizedValue: string = isBlank(value) ? "" : (isDate(value) ? moment(value).format("YYYY-MM-DD") : "");
        this._renderer.setElementProperty(this._elementRef.nativeElement, "value", normalizedValue);
    }

    registerOnChange(fn: (_: any) => void): void {
        this.onChange = (value: string) => {
            var date: moment.Moment = moment(value, "YYYY-MM-DD");
            var newValue: Date = date.isValid() ? date.toDate() : undefined;
            fn(newValue);
        };
    }

    registerOnTouched(fn: () => void): void {
        this.onTouched = fn;
    }
}
```

I feel I'm almost there, but not quite!

**update** When the form first loads, everything is hunky dory, but when I try to pick a new date, the browser complains about the format. **/update**

The error I can see in my devtools is:

> The specified value "Fri Sep 09 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (GMT Summer Time)" does not conform to the required format, "yyyy-MM-dd".

I have burned a bit of time tweaking the code and moving things around. I've also tried to make a call to `writeValue` from inside `onChange` ([as can be seen in this plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/L9BkYaLUuHiBFClZxOwk?p=preview)), but I still saw the error...

Has anyone done this? Is there something obvious in my code that I've missed?

Comment: i have some questions so i can try and help,  is writeValue triggered? how ? if not, how do you expect it to be triggered. do you know which lines the error coming from? (Error stacktrace)

Comment: What do I have to do to reproduce this issue? I added your code to the Plunker you providedd https://plnkr.co/edit/uFOEUrPIBthcfBcPdl9K?p=preview

Comment: Just a hint. You shouldn't import from `src` subdirectory of other packages. That' also actively prevented in newer versions AFAIK. `import { isBlank, isDate } from "@angular/forms/src/facade/lang";` is subject to be removed anyway AFAIK.

Comment: @HagaiCo the error is displayed in the console and its source is the browser not the code, there is no stack

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer thank you for the tip; I'm aware, however it does work and in some cases it's the only way to make it work as some things are not exported

Comment: Can you add console.log to writeValue? To make sure it is called and what is the value? Also, can you give the template that should invoke this directive? (How exactly you expect it to be called)

Comment: @HagaiCo it reads to me like you're not familiar with ng2 and the concepts referred to in this question; is that the case?

Comment: Nope, ive already written value accessor in RC4 (calendar component) but if you dont want my help what can i do..

Comment: @HagaiCo just checking mate, no need to get defensive; I'll update the question with some more information and perhaps do a plnkr with an example in the evening (I'm at work now); as for how I expect it to be called, that's ng internals; ngModel will use this value accessor for input type=date when it's included in the directives, as it does

Comment: Great, and you are using [ngModel] (with []) right? Is it bound to a form?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123231/discussion-between-the-bearded-llama-and-hagaico).

Comment: What browser are you using? I can't reproduce in Chrome.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Chrome latest v

Answer (score 1):

Admittedly using a more up to date version of Angular (2.1.0) but the changes should apply and you can see the model binds correctly to your formatted string, here's a Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/8U0o0m49646tMH0kr1Mx?p=preview

The only change to your code is:

```
registerOnChange(fn: (_: any) => void): void {
    this.onChange = fn;
}
```

This does not have the display text vary as that is, to the best of my knowledge, bound to the input type="date" as an element and cannot be overridden. A quick search takes me to [Is there any way to change input type="date" format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372038/is-there-any-way-to-change-input-type-date-format) which seems to back this claim up.